# ¿Como cambiar el idioma a mi pagina web con angularjs?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, aplicación-web, spring-mvc

Como puedo cambiar y con que, el idioma de mi página ya sea con un selector de idioma o automáticamente todo el texto, al idioma seleccionado.

He visto que con angular se descargan archivos de idioma .js o los Locale, pero solo cambia algunos parámetros como las divisas, fechas, etc.

Comment: Escribe un ejemplo de los que tienes ahora pues hay muchas formas de cambiar los idiomas y locales. Creo que estas intentando abarcar demasiado pues cambiar de idioma y cambiar los formatos de las fechas no se hace de la misma manera, además en tu pregunta dices "de preferencia Angularjs" por lo que no aclaras si el cambio lo harás en el cliente o en el server.

Comment: Lo quiero cambiar en el cliente aparte de las constantes como divisa, formato de fechas, pues algún texto o texto de botones,  ejemplo botón de cerrar sesión  cerrar sesión/logout

Answer (score 1):

Buenas, no sé si lo he entendido bien. ¿Quieres que el user pueda elegir entre varios idiomas en tu página?. 
Yo sinceramente lo haría con "hard coding", es decir ofrecería una página de inicio en la que antes que nada el usuario tenga que elegir en que idioma quiere ver tu pagina. Por ejemplo:

index.html:

"Selecciona el idioma"  [Español]
"Sprache auswählen".    [Alemán]

Y a dependiendo de que haya seleccionado el usuario redirigir a un index_es.html o a un index_de.html.

Otra alternativa seria la de usar como mencionas angular translate. Te dejo aquí un ejemplo de como funcionaría: [Angular Traslate](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/07_multi-language)